# Unable to get accuracy beyond 30% for MNIST expert example Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I followed the MNIST experts example on tensorflow website, but having real difficulty getting anywhere close to the figure suggested by the website.

With 20k iterations, batch size 50, and either GPU/CPU used as device I hardly get 30% accuracy.

Can you please help?

```
def main(args):
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

w_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv_2d(x_image, w_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

w_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv_2d(h_pool1, w_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# Densely Connected Layer
w_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

w_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, w_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0})

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1})
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0
            })
            print("step %d, training accuracy %g" %(i, train_accuracy))


        print("test accuracy %g" %accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    tf.app.run(main = main)

Comment: in order to do argmax in y_conv it should be softmax probabilities, and you aren't applying softmax to those values.

Comment: This is being done while calculating the cross entropy, where y_conv is taken as logits.
softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits -> Isnt this supposed to convert to softmax and then apply cross entropy?

Comment: Yes, but you are doing argmax to y_conv which doesn't have softmax applied. You applied softmax + cross entropy and saved that into the cross_entropy variable.

Comment: Softmax simply rescales the values so this shouldn't make a difference.